# NodeJS Websocket (ws) how communicate between different clients?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ajax, websocket

I have 2 clients, I need client1 gives information to client2 and this receive an alert of it, I'm implementing Websocket "ws" with NodeJS for this.

Client1 web page receive an answer via AJAX and send information to server.js in JSON format, like this example:
**/mysite_folder/client1/client1.php**

```
<script>
var userorder = $("#user").val(); //client2 username who will receive information

$.post("myscript.php",{
  my: variables
}).done(function(response){
var wsUri = "wss://www.mysite.com:3000/sockets/";
var output;

websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
websocket.onopen = onOpen; 
websocket.onclose = onClose; 
websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
websocket.onerror = onError;

function onOpen(evt){

output = {
 "status": "ASSIGNED",
 "user":  userorder
 };
 doSend(JSON.stringify(output));
}

function doSend(message){ 
 websocket.send(message);
 websocket.close();
}

function onMessage(evt){    
}

function onClose(evt){ 
 location.reload();
}

function onError(evt){
}
});

</script>
```

After client1 send information, connection closes and refresh client1 page. My server receives this JSON information like this: **/mysite_folder/sockets/server.js**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
fs = require('fs');

var cfg = {
    ssl: true,
    port: 3000,
    ssl_key: '/path/of/sslkey',
    ssl_cert: '/path/of/sslcert'
};

var httpServ = ( cfg.ssl ) ? require('https') : require('http');

var app      = null;

var processRequest = function( req, res ) {
res.writeHead(200);
res.end("All glory to WebSockets!\n");
};

if ( cfg.ssl ) {

app = httpServ.createServer({

   // providing server with  SSL key/cert
   key: fs.readFileSync( cfg.ssl_key ),
   cert: fs.readFileSync( cfg.ssl_cert )

}, processRequest ).listen( cfg.port );

} else {
 app = httpServ.createServer( processRequest ).listen( cfg.port );
}

var wss = new WebSocketServer( { server: app } );
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){
console.log("User connected");

 ws.on('message', function incoming(message){      
   var info = JSON.parse(message); //receive client1 info
   if(info.status=="ASSIGNED"){
     ws.send(info.user); //send client2 username
   }       
 });
});
```

Parsing JSON and comparing that information status is "ASSIGNED" I need "info.user" send to client2 page displaying an alert message, so in client2 I wrote like this example: **/mysite_folder/client2/client2.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var user = $("#user").val(); //client2 username

 var wsUri = "wss://www.mysite.com:3000/sockets/";
 var output;

 websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
 websocket.onopen = onOpen;
 websocket.onclose = onClose;
 websocket.onmessage = onMessage;
 websocket.onerror = onError;

 function onOpen(evt){
 }

 function doSend(message){
 }

 function onMessage(evt){ 
  if(user==evt){ //if client2 username sent by server is the same with client2 username logged in the page, make an alert
    alert("Your order was ASSIGNED");
  }
  websocket.close();
 }

 function onClose(evt){
 }

 function onError(evt){
 }
});
```

Connections works fine, client1 is working well, but in client2 doesn't happen anything, how can I make client2 get this alert?

**UPDATE**

On **server.js** I added a broadcast method like this:

```
var wss = new WebSocketServer( { server: app } );

// Broadcast to all.
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(data) {
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
  if ( client.readyState == WebSocketServer.OPEN) {
    client.send(data);
  }      
  });
};

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws){
console.log("User connected");

ws.on('message', function incoming(message){

    //Broadcast to everyone else
    var info = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log(info.user); //shows username in console

    wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
      if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocketServer.OPEN) {
        if(info.status=="ASSIGNED"){
            client.send(info.user);
        }
      }
    });     
});
});
```

But client2 is still doesn't receiving message from server and not displaying the alert.

I would like some help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your sending data back down the same socket connection you receive the message i.e. `ws.send(info.user)`, `ws` refers to that client connection only.

The server has a [broadcast](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/master/lib/WebSocketServer.js#L166) method you can use which sends the message to *all* active connections

```
wss.broadcast(info.user);
```

Comment: According to documentation https://github.com/websockets/ws#broadcast-example ,  I created a broadcast function, no error displayed now but client2 is still doesn't happen anything.

Comment: @NekoLopez I've linked to the code directly, it would appear the library already has a `broadcast` method. Either way, this is the approach you use for notifying all clients, you'll need to debug and make sure your client is _definitely_ connected & the data is being sent.

Comment: Clients are connected, but it seems broadcasting is not working, I added a line before if(info.status=="ASSIGNED") showing a message in console (console.log('Message sent to clients')) and console shows nothing